# alert() in AJAX callback shows [Object object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am calling the following function to do stuff in the Spring Controller. The problem is that the `alert` message is not containing the message that I am sending, but prints `[Object object]`. Is there a way to send the particular message, according to the result, print it and also send the Status code?

```js
function saveButton(button) {
  var data = gatherData(button);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/editRecord',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      alert(getData().done(error));
    }
  });
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/editRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String editRecord(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) 
{
  Map<String, String[]> map = httpRequest.getParameterMap();

  // do stuff

  String messageToReturn = "";
  if (userService.updateTable(pr.getUpdateQuery(fileMap))) 
  {
    messageToReturn = "Operation was successful";
  } 
  else
    messageToReturn = "Operation failed";

  return messageToReturn;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly why you should never use `alert()` for debugging - it coerces all data provided to it to a string. Use `console.log(data)` or `console.dir(data)` instead

Comment: The problem was not about that it returns an object. The question was about printing the message which is sent by the Spring controller.

Comment: If you're getting an object back, then you are not returning that string. You need to first figure out what the contents of the object that *is* being returned is, then *why* that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your method return `text` (i.e. messageToReturn) not JSON. You can produce `text` as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="text/plain")
public @ResponseBody String editRecord(HttpServletRequest httpRequest){}
```

And it this case, remove  `dataType: 'json'` from AJAX method.

---

But if you return JSON, then you can type it in the JSON format.

```
messageToReturn = "{\"check\":\"Operation was successful\"}"; //(without produces="text/plain")
```

And access it like this :

```
success: function(response) {
 console.log(response.check);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using `ObjectMapper` of Jackson library (jackson-databind). Just modify your method as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editRecord", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String editRecord(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) 
{
  Map<String, String[]> map = httpRequest.getParameterMap();

  // do stuff

  String messageToReturn = "";
  if (userService.updateTable(pr.getUpdateQuery(fileMap))) 
  {
    messageToReturn = "Operation was successful";
  } 
  else
    messageToReturn = "Operation failed";

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(messageToReturn);
  return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(response) {
  alert(response.responseText);
},
```

Answer (score -1):

The data you send from the spring-controller is available via response.data.

```
success: function (response) {
  alert(response.data);
},
error: function (error) {
  alert(getData().done(error.data));
}
```